# Cortar uma quantidade de caracteres dentro de uma célula com VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

tenho uma dúvida de VBA!

Utilizando um código VBA importei dados de uma planilha em excel para outra planilha. Entretanto, na coluna A, comecando pela célula A2 a informação copiada está no seguinte formato "21/11/2020 7:00:00".
Eu preciso elabolar um códico em VBA que limpe nessas células dessa coluna a informação 7:00:000 e mantenha 21/11/2020, e preciso que ele repita isso para todos os dados da coluna A e finalizar quando não houver mais dados naquela coluna. Abaixo segue o código que eu estou usando para importar os dados da planilha, eu preciso incorporar a esse código.

```
Sub ImportarArquivo()

Dim caminho As Variant
Dim este As Workbook
Dim outro As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

caminho = Application.GetOpenFilename

If caminho = False Then Exit Sub

Workbooks.Open caminho, , True
Set este = ThisWorkbook
Set outro = ActiveWorkbook

outro.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
Planilha22.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

outro.Close False

 Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
     
Sheets("Tela Inicial").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Você provavelmente precisa criar um while para percorrer linha a linha e utilizar o comando Left (A1, 10) onde o A1 será sua variável.